# Comments or metadata in shp files?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I'm trying to somehow add metadata to shapefiles using geopandas; for example, the name of the program that created the polygons. This way, I can have a link back to the source files. How can I do this?

Comment: `gdf_with_meta = gdf.assign(filename=source_file)`

Comment: @PaulH: Sorry, I didn't get that...

Comment: So ArcGIS / shapefiles has the concept of a `.shp.xml` file where you can store metadata (see eg https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77707/how-to-provide-meanings-metadata-of-attributes-fields-with-shapefiles or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile). But, I don't think this is supported by GDAL (what geopandas uses to read shapefiles).